# Google Cloud Container Builder - Build Docker container from Go source with vendored dependencies

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, google-container-registry, govendor, google-container-builder

**Background**

Related question: [Google Container Builder: How to install govendor dependencies during build step?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46395187/google-container-builder-how-to-install-govendor-dependencies-during-build-step)

I am trying to use Google Cloud Container Builder to automate the building of my Docker containers using Build Triggers.

My code is in Go, and I have a `vendor` folder (checked in to Git) in my project root which contains all of my Go dependencies.

My project has four binaries that need to be Dockerized, structured as follows:

```
vendor/
   ...
program1/
    program1.go
    main/
        main.go
        Dockerfile
program2/
    program2.go
    main/
        main.go
        Dockerfile
...
```

Each program's Dockerfile is simple:

```
FROM alpine
ADD main main
ENTRYPOINT ["/main"]
```

I have a Build Trigger set up to track my `master` branch. The trigger runs the following build request (`cloudbuild.yaml`), which makes use of the open sourced Docker build step:

```
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args: ['build', '-t', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/program1:0.1.15-$SHORT_SHA', '.']
  dir: 'program1/main'

  ... (repeated for each program)
  (images, tags omitted)
```

To summarize, my current build process is as follows:

1. Edit code.
2. Build each Go executable using `go build`. The executable is called `main`, and is saved in the `programX/main/` directory, alongside `main.go`.
3. Commit and push code (since the `main` executables are tracked by Git) to my master branch.
4. Build Trigger makes four Docker images using the `main` file built in step 1.

**Goal**

I would like to eliminate Step 1 from my build process, so that I no longer need to compile my executables locally, and do not need to track my `main` executables in Git.

In sum, here is my ideal process:

1. Edit code, commit, push to remote.
2. Build Trigger compiles all four programs, builds all four images.
3. Relax :)

**Attempted solution**

I used the open source [Go build step](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders/tree/master/go), as follows:

`cloudbuild.yaml`: (updated)

```
steps:
- id: 'build-program1'
  name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/go'
  args: ['build', '-a', '-installsuffix', 'cgo', '-ldflags', '''-w''', '-o', 'main', './main.go']
  env: ['PROJECT_ROOT=/workspace', 'CGO_ENABLED=0', 'GOOS=linux']
  dir: 'program1/main'
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args: ['build', '-t', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/program1:0.1.15-$SHORT_SHA', '.']
  dir: 'program1/main'
  waitFor: ['build-program1']

  ... (repeated for each program)
  (images, tags omitted)
```

After trying various combinations of setting PROJECT_ROOT and GOPATH in the `env` field of the `build-programX`, I kept getting the same error for every single package used in my project (file path varies):

```
cannot find package "github.com/acoshift/go-firebase-admin" in any of
Step #0 - "build-program1": /usr/local/go/src/github.com/acoshift/go-firebase-admin (from $GOROOT) 
Step #0 - "build-program1": /workspace/auth/main/gopath/src/github.com/acoshift/go-firebase-admin (from $GOPATH)
```

It's not even looking for a vendor directory?

**What next?**

My guess is that one of the following is true:

1. I am not specifying the `GOPATH`/`PROJECT_ROOT` correctly in the build request file. But if so, what is the correct setting?
2. My project is not structured correctly.
3. What I am trying to do is impossible :(*
4. I need to make a custom build step, somehow.
5. The version of Go used is old - but how can I check this?

I can find no examples online of what I am trying to achieve, and I find GCP's documentation on this subject quite lacking.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed the problem (but not exactly sure how...), thanks to these changes:

1. Set `PROJECT_ROOT` to `my_root`, such that the code I want to compile sits at `my_root/program1/main/main.go` (thanks to John Asmuth for his answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46526875/6905609)
2. Remove the `dirs` field for the Go build step
3. Set the `-o` flag to `./program1/main/main`, and the final build arg to `./program1/main/main.go`

Previously I was `cd`ing into the `program1/main` directory during the build step, and for some reason `go build` was looking for packages within `my_root/program1/main` instead of `my_root`. Weird!

Comment: Could you tell me please what command line did you apply and where please?

Answer (score 3):

The issue is with #1: `PROJECT_ROOT` refers to the desired import path of your binaries. For example, if in `program1/main/main.go` you import `"github.com/foo/bar/program1"` to get the package defined in `program1/program1.go`, you'd set `PROJECT_ROOT=github.com/foo/bar`.

Comment: I don't follow... I can set `PROJECT_ROOT` only once, but in `program1/main/main.go` I import several different packages: `my_root/program1`, `my_root/utils`, `github.com/golang/glog`, to name a few (`my_root` is the name of the overall Go package, and is the directory name of my source code), so I'm not sure what to set `PROJECT_ROOT` to.

Comment: I tried setting `PROJECT_ROOT` to: `my_root` (this should have worked, I think), `my_root/program1`, `program1`, but all resulted in the same problem. Since `my_root` is not an actual folder in my Git repo, maybe the Go build step doesn't "know" about the `my_root` directory, which messes up my paths?

Comment: (apologies for the spam, just keep getting more info to share)

When I set `PROJECT_ROOT` to `my_root`, I get several errors that look like this:

`cannot find package "my_root/utils" in any of`
`/usr/local/go/src/my_root/utils (from $GOROOT)`
`/workspace/program1/main/gopath/src/my_root/utils (from $GOPATH)`

The latter error file path looks absurd to me... seems to be looking inside `program1/main/`!

Comment: never mind, I played around with the `dirs` field and it seems to work now. Thanks!

Comment: As you discovered, if you set `PROJECT_ROOT` you need to run the `gcr.io/cloud-builders/go` step from the directory containing things directly inside the root - the env var tells the builder that "this directory is the project root, and call it <whatever>".

Comment: @IsmailKhan could you provide the setup you did to avoid error "cannot find package " please